# Phpmyadmin error in new 4.0.7

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just upgraded to 4.0.7 and now when I click on a lot of links, I have an error.
Example: I select a table and click on "Structure" link on top, then I have :

```
SELECT tracking_active FROM.WHERE db_name =  'arns_internet'
AND table_name =  'niusers'
ORDER BY version DESC

MySQL a répondu: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE db_name = 'arns_internet'  AND table_name = 'niusers'  ORDER BY ver' at line 1
```

And the same error message for "operations" link or Search link and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you did not close your browser since the upgrade, or you are using PHP older than 5.2.

Comment: Correct! The browser was not closed after upgrade!